# Bitmaps swallowing more memory than expected

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I am developing a 2D RPG game for android and have run into a huge obstacle when loading maps. I use Tiled to create the maps and a 3rd party, open source TMX loader to load the maps into the game.

One of my maps is 100x100 tiles. Each tile is 16x16 pixels and I am using the RGB_565 format for the Bitmap I create from the TMX file. This should create a 1600x1600 Bitmap with 4 bytes for each pixel, meaning the entire Bitmap should amount to 1600x1600x4 bytes in the memory (10MB). However, this is not the case as the memory in use (reported by methods in the Runtime class). When the map is loaded, the used memory shoots up from around 13-15MB to over 120MB. I cannot possibly see how this is happening.

Do Bitmaps have that much overhead?

Whenever a new map is loaded, the old map is disposed of and it's Bitmap built from the TMX is recycled. This seems to sometimes have no effect on the memory usage.

My actual question is why Bitmaps with a calculated size of 10MB consume over 100MB of memory.